# How to maintain many-to-many relationship between feature class and table with multiple disconnected editors?

Tags: data, enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-engine, algorithm, vb.net

I have an application coded with VB.NET (ArcGIS Engine) and its functionality is:

1. digitize a parcel and enter information for its owners, so i have a M-N relationship between them.
2. every parcel has it stones  so an M-N relationship ...

i have two PCs where the application is installed, and I am using them in disconnected mode.

The problem is that I want to be able to export daba and import it between the 2 PCs without losing data or the relationship.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of a more detailed description of your system, I would suggest to use Versioning when there are multiple editors.

Study [this document](http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0110/versioning101.html) which explains every thing you need to know with the same parcel division example.

If you use above given method you do not have to import or export the data.

Answer (score 0):

This might be speaking outside of geo-spatial lexicon, but a many-to-many relationship is best done with an associative table.  Creating a third table with unique ids and creating inside this table all relative relationships and then joining this third table up to one of the original tables by a corresponding field.

Comment: I have assumed that the asker is already on top of Relationship Classes for the many-to-many relate and is now trying to ensure that the middle table remains writable by multiple disconnected editors without loss of integrity.  Geodatabase versioning, as suggested by @AbhjitGujar, is what I would look at first.